# Textbook Recommendations: Reviewing Calculus for Educators

Tags: education, online-resources

I tutor first and second year university students, typically with their physics coursework. This semester I have been asked to also teach/tutor calculus 2 & 3 (integral & multivariable). It's been quite a few years since I took these courses so I was hoping to find a text that would work as a refresher on the topics -- especially one that takes a novel approach to teaching the subject for my own pedagogical benefit. I was curious if there was something analogous to Needham's 'Visual Complex Analysis' for calculus.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you doing this in any kind of official capacity at a particular university? Or more specifically, do your students for the most part come from a single university? If so, it wouldn't be a bad idea to familiarise yourself with the books they use, regardless of quality or pedagogical approach.

Comment: Imo vector calculus and contour integration is something you should look into. Then again i do not know you , nor your university nor students. And I am not a teacher myself. So take with a lot of salt

Comment: Also I agree with Arthur. You should know the past of your students. Also is this question maybe a bit personal or opinion based dunno

Comment: For 1-variable calculus, maybe [**Calculus in Context. The Five College Calculus Project**](http://www.science.smith.edu/~callahan/intromine.html) by James Callahan, et al. (1995, 2008) -- see [this answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/13905/745) for some comments about it. For multivariable calculus, maybe [**Div, Grad, Curl, and All That. An Informal Text on Vector Calculus**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0393925161) by Schey (2004, 4th edition). Given your background and purpose, I chose these for pedagogical reasons, not for high levels of rigor or hard problems.